# OpenLayers: Drawing polygons and points then dragging them

Tags: javascript, openlayers

Looking to solve a problem I am having with open layers.

**First problem:** I have an entity and it has a collection of waypoints and lines drawn on the map. I want to drag the polygon line AND the points together.

**Second problem:** Is there also a way for me to add unique layers or features for when I have multiple entities? I don't want to move the waypoints or lines of a different entity so can I use open layers to draw lines that are unique and only accessible by name?

I am new to open layers and still trying to figure out the best way to navigate the api documentation.

Comment: Not sure why I am getting negative reputation. The question itself is trying to make sense of the way open layers wants to handle layers and features so I can create unique features for me to access when an entity is selected. If I dump code here it wont make it easier to help discuss the required constructs that open layers requires in order to have unique collections of data on a map that are drag-able based on the currently selected entity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First problem answer:** combine the features of lines and points into a single feature "collection" (ol.collection).

**Second problem answer:** for the unique entities you should append the various features used to the entity itself. When you select the entity return the collection of features you wish you manipulate that the selected entity had.

```
    //get the selected entity that had the waypoints appended to the object
    const selectedEntity = this.entities.get(this.selected);
    //combine the points and the polygon line into one array to turn into a collection
    var linesAndPoints = selectedEntity.waypointFeatures.icons.concat(selectedEntity.waypointFeatures.lines);
    //create an ol.collection object to add to the translate interaction
    let featuresCollection = new ol.Collection(linesAndPoints);
    this.myTranslate = new ol.interaction.Translate({
      condition: ol.events.condition.click,
      hitTolerance: 5,
      features: featuresCollection
    });
```